# Firestore performance issues when compared to Firestore emulator

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My app can have a large amount of writes, reads and updates (can even go above 10000) under certain circumstances.

While developing the application locally, these operations usually take a few seconds at most (great!) however, it can easily take minutes when running the application on google cloud, to the point that the Firebase function times out.

I developed a controlled test in a separate project, whose sole purpose is to write, get and delete thousands of items for bench-marking. These were the results (averaged out from several tests):

```
Local Emulator:
5000 items,                   4.2s write,  2.2s delete
5000 items, batch mode ON,    0.75s write, 0.11s delete

Cloud Firestore:
100 items,                    15.8s write, 14.5s delete
1000 items, batch mode ON,    4.8s write,  3.0s delete
5000 items, async mode ON,    10.2s write, 8.0s delete
5000 items, batch & async ON, 4.5s write,  3.9s delete
```

NOTE: My local emulator crashes whenever I try to perform db operations async (which is a problem for another day) but it is why I was unable to test the write/delete speeds asynchronously locally. Also, write and read values usually vary +-25% between runs.

However, as you can see, the fact that my local emulator is faster in its slowest mode compared to the fastest test in the cloud definitely raises some questions.

Could it be that I have some sort of configuration issue? or is it just that these numbers are standard for firestore? Here is the (summarised) typescript code if you wish to try it:

```
functions.runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540, memory: "2GB" }).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  //getting the settings from the request
  var data = req.body;
  var numWrites: number = data.numWrites;
  var syncMode: boolean = !data.asyncMode;
  var batchMode: boolean = data.batchMode;
  var batchLimit: number = data.batchLimit;

  //pre-run setup
  var dbObj = {
    number: 123,
    string: "abc",
    boolean: true,
    object: { var1: "var1", num1: 1 },
    array: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  };
  var collection = db.collection("testCollection");
  var startTime = moment();

  //insert requested number of items, using requested settings
  var allInserts: Promise<any>[] = [];
  if (!batchMode) { //sequential writes
    for (var i = 0; i < numWrites; i++) {
      var set = collection.doc().set(dbObj);
      allInserts.push(set);
      if (syncMode) await set;
    }
  } else { //batch writes
    var batch = db.batch();
    for (var i = 1; i <= numWrites; i++) {
      batch.set(collection.doc(), dbObj);
      if (i % batchLimit === 0) {
        var commit = batch.commit();
        allInserts.push(commit);
        batch = db.batch();
        if (syncMode) await commit;
      }
    }
  }

  //some logging information. Getting items to delete
  var numInserts = allInserts.length;
  await Promise.all(allInserts);
  var insertTime = moment();
  var alldocs = (await collection.get()).docs;
  var numDocs = alldocs.length;
  var getTime = moment();

  //deletes all of the items in the collection
  var allDeletes: Promise<any>[] = [];
  if (!batchMode) { //sequential deletes
    for (var doc of alldocs) {
      var del = doc.ref.delete();
      allDeletes.push(del);
      if (syncMode) await del;
    }
  } else { //batch deletes
    var batch = db.batch();
    for (var i = 1; i <= numDocs; i++) {
      var doc = alldocs[i - 1];
      batch.delete(doc.ref);
      if (i % batchLimit === 0) {
        var commit = batch.commit();
        allDeletes.push(commit);
        batch = db.batch();
        if (syncMode) await commit;
      }
    }
  }

  var numDeletes = allDeletes.length;
  await Promise.all(allDeletes);
  var deleteTime = moment();

  res.status(200).send(/* a whole bunch of metrics for analysis */);
});
```

EDIT: just to clarify, the UI does not perform these write operations, so latency between the end-user machine and cloud servers should (in theory) not cause any major latency issues. The communication to the database is handled fully by `Firebase Functions`

EDIT 2: I have run this test on two deployments, one in Europe and another in US. Both took around the same amount of time to run, even though my ping to these two servers are vastly different

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to have faster response with the local emulator than Cloud Firestore as the remote environment adds the network traffic that takes time.

For large amounts of operations from a single source the recommendation is to use [batch operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) as these will reduce the  transcactions, and with it Round trips.

And the reason for the Async mode to be faster is that the caller is not waiting for each transaction to be completed before sending the next one So it also makes sense that the calls are faster with it.

The Times you have on the table seem normal to me.

Just as an additional thing to optimize make sure that the region where your firestore database is located is the closest one to your location.

Comment: I'll second what José said, it's likely network latency. You can check gcping.com to see what your network latency from your machine to the Cloud region you're using is. Multiple it out by the number of round trips you're doing to give you an idea of the added latency the network causes.

Comment: My code is not the UI writing to firestore, it is the cloud functions talking to firestore. surely the latency between google-cloud-functions and firestore is negligible enough that it should not affect the performance